# Solve this equation $z^3-(2+4i)z^2-3(1-3i)z+14-2i=0,z\in C$

Tags: cubics

Solve following equation 
$$z^3-(2+4i)z^2-3(1-3i)z+14-2i=0,z\in C$$

Try $z=a+bi$,then It's ugly can you more simple ?

Comment: There is a general formula for [cubic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots). Maybe there is an easier approach, I don't know.

Comment: You could try the Cardano method. It is a bit of an ugly formula but it should work just as well as the formula for the second degree polynomials

Comment: I have given the general solutions to both quartic and cubic here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4601016/151732 You can start lower down from the cubic solution. Please work through the algebra yourself, as it is *not* pleasant. According to Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%5E3-%282%2B4i%29z%5E2-3%281-3i%29z%2B14-2i%3D0 , there are no "nice" roots so it's unlikely any "clever tricks" apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can try Cardano method, but sometimes it is worthwhile to search for "gaussian integers" solution first, that is, solutions of the form $a+bi$, where $a,b$ are integers. Of course, that method fails in case there are no "rational" solutions. If $z=a+bi$, is such a solution, then 
$$
a+bi\mid 14-2i=i(1+i)^3(1+2i)^2
$$
Therefore, $a+bi$ is of the form $a+bi=i^{\ell}(1+i)^m(1+2i)^n$, where $0\leqslant m\leqslant 3$, $0\leqslant n\leqslant 2$ and $0\leqslant \ell\leqslant 3$. In this case there are $48$ options to check.

Comment: But unfortunately none of them help in this case.

Comment: I found the same thing @almagest.  Where did this problem come from?