# Find the nature of the roots of the following quartic function:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

> $$x^4 + 2x^3 -13x^2 -14x + 24 = 0$$

I tried factoring, but it didn't seem to work out. I tried pulling out an $x^3$, but no progress. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve a quartic equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103988/how-to-solve-a-quartic-equation)

Comment: Are you actually trying to find the roots of this polynomial or, as you wrote in the title, only trying to determine their nature? You can do the latter with Descartes’ rule of signs and, if that gives you an ambiguous result, Sturm’s theorem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start looking for the rational roots by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). Because the polynomial is monic, they'll need to be integers. We start with $\pm1$: $1$ is a root, but $-1$ isn't. We eventually find the roots are $1,\,-2,\,3,\,-4$.

Answer (score 0):

$x=1$ is a root so divide by $x-1$ and try to factor the resulting cubic. 
$x=3$ is also a root so divide by $x-3$ and solve the resulting quadratic.

Comment: How did you determine that x=1 was a root?

Comment: @BobSmith By trying it.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^4 + 2x^3 -13x^2 -14x + 24=$$
$$=x^4-x^3+3x^3-3x^2-10x^2+10x-24x+24=(x-1)(x^3+3x^2-10x-24)=$$
$$=(x-1)(x^3+2x^2+x^2+2x-12x-24)=(x-1)(x+2)(x^2+x-12).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: how were you able to break up the term

Comment: @Bob Smith We know that $1$ is a root of the equation, which by the Bézout's theorem says that there is a factor $x-1$ and I made this factoring.