# Solve a cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

I need to analytically solve a cubic equation which has the form: $x^3 + bx^2 + c = 0.$ In this case, $b = 1-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{N}, c = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N y_i}{N}.$ I am not looking for numerical methods. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: have you searched for cardano-tartaglia relationships?

Comment: to gain modern intuition, try https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+a+x%5E3%2Bb+x%2Bc%3D0 .

Comment: @Colver is suggesting [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula) technique. You'll need to set $y=x+b/3$ first.

Comment: If you put $t=\frac 1x$ and divide through by $c (\neq 0)$ you will get a standard form in $t$ and any article or book which covers solutions of the cubic will give both method and formula.

Comment: Oopss https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+a+x%5E3%2Bb+x%5E2%2Bc%3D0 .

Comment: You can follow my method (describes both quartic and cubic) in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103988/solving-x4-10x3-21x2-40x-100-0/4601016#4601016